# Error when trying to only construct DropoutWrapper operation if dropout rate > 0 using tf.cond()

Tags: python, tensorflow

To see if it makes the training of my model more efficient, I am attempting to only call TensorFlow's `DropoutWrapper` operation if the specified `dropout_rate` is greater than 0 (rather than creating the operation, but not actually adding any dropout). I am also trying to do the same thing with adding L2 Regularization to my loss value - only perform my method for calculating the L2 penalty if the `l2_alpha` multiplier value is greater than zero.

Here is how I have attempted to achieve it for dropout:

```
layers = []
for layer_size in self.hidden_sizes:
    cell = self.cell_type(layer_size)
    cell = tf.cond(
        self.dropout_rate > 0.0,
        lambda: tensorflow.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=(1.0 - self.dropout_rate)),
        lambda: cell
    )
    layers.append(cell)
stacked_layers = tensorflow.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(layers)
```

This is throwing the error:

```
`TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl.DropoutWrapper'> to Tensor. Contents: <tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl.DropoutWrapper object at 0x7fa51b84bbe0>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.`
```

Is there a way I can achieve this using `tf.cond()` or any other way?

Comment: Is `self.dropout_rate` a variable calculated by other processes, e.g., Bayesian Optimization or annealing? If not, then why not just use plain if ... else ...? If it is indeed the case, I'd say exactly 0 is unlikely to reach in practice, right?

Comment: `dropout_rate` is a placeholder and so won't be populated with a value until the Session is started. An if...else... needs to be evaluated at the time of graph creation. The point of it is to apply dropout in training and not during prediction time. I will look at the `DropoutWrapper` source code - perhaps it checks if the value is 0 and returns immediately anyway.

Comment: The problem is that you are adding an object of type DropoutWrapper to the layers list while you need the result of the call of DropoutWrapper. If you have the placeholder of the input to the layer just do 
``tensorflow.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=(1.0 - self.dropout_rate))(input)``

Comment: @KOB Unfortunately, the source code says if dropout_rate is not `float`, it will do dropout. I think, since `fn()` in `tf.cond` has to be tensor, you could initialize a `DropoutWrapper` cell (which is class) as well (just give it a different name, e.g., `cell_drop`, or key in an op dictionary). The reason is that initialization of a class does not take much computation resources, only `__call__` does. Thus, when you apply the cell, you could do something like `outputs = tf.cond(self.dropout_rate > 0.0, cell_drop.apply(inputs), cell.apply(inputs))`.